# Term for when a 2D tesselation is closed in 3D shapes?

Tags: terminology, tiling

I dont know how to describe this , the examples I can give is trehadron is made of triangle faces, cube is made of square faces, this picture is made of diamond shaped 2D non regular(?) faces.

I know when non regular shapes are used to tile a plane, but what is it called when shapes like this are made?
[image]

Comment: (Convex) [Polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron) maybe?

Comment: A polyhedron whose faces are identical (in a certain sense) is called an [isohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isohedron). This one in particular appears to be a [pentagonal hexecontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_hexecontahedron).

Comment: When the faces are identical without any other conditions, the polyhedron is called *monohedral*.